# Package: git-1.7.6.1-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge) Requires: libcurl.so.3

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

After I run `yum install git`

it shows the error

```
Error: Package: git-1.7.6.1-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libcurl.so.3
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Do I need to install libcurl.so.3 or download git from the web and install?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are trying to install the **el5** version of `git` (git-1.7.6.1-1.**el5**.rf.i386). I had the same issue as [described here](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&topic_id=33231&forum=56).

I fixed it by enabling the rpmforge extras and it picked up el6 of git (then could just yum install)

I'm sure this is an issue with the centos default repos, I mean it should install el6 by default?

Comment: i have enabled it, also didarestart, but still its pointing to el5. Plz help

Comment: ok. Norrad's answer worked

Comment: For me it was a combination of this and Norrad's answers. After installing the el6 version I had to run "yum clean all" as yum was still reading the old cached repo data.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem under CentOS 6.3. Running `yum provides git` gave me two choices:

```
 git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
 git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
```

So, I did a `yum install git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64` and it installed the .el6 version of `git`, along with `perl-Error` and `perl-Git`, and issues no errors and NO missing `libcurl.so.3` files!

Comment: worked for me too. Thanx

Answer (score 4):

I don't think installing the `curl` package installs `libcurl.so.3`.  The `curl` package provides the `curl` program and associated files, not the library.

For Centos, the package you need is probably called something like `curl-devel`.

I'm a surprised `yum` didn't offer to install the dependencies for you.  On CentOS 5.6, the `yum` man page says that `yum install` "Is  used  to  install the latest version of a package or group of packages while ensuring that all dependencies are satisfied".  I suppose it's possible that the dependencies aren't configured correctly, but that seems unlikely for something as popular as `git`.

Try `yum install curl-devel` followed by `yum install git`.

Comment: Agree, except I don't find very recent curl-devel rpm for CentOS6. +1

Answer (score 1):

First off, under root, at `/etc/yum.conf` edit the file, and comment out the exclude line with a leading `;` i.e. `;exclude` (I use WinSCP at http://winscp.net to log in as it has a built-in modified notepad editor, along with PuTTY for SSH access.)

After reading the above about installing `curl-devel`, it didn't work for me. But `yum reinstall curl-devel` worked. I then followed that up with `yum install git`, and it proceeded to install git and 2 additional needed files.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

`$ yum install git-all.noarch` which doesn't depend on architectures.

Comment: Works for me in my client server

Answer (score 0):

You should install <del>[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)</del>, since it is [listed as a direct dependency for git](http://sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#git) (alongside openssl-1.0.0d, libssh2, libiconv, libintl, libidn, expat and zlib)

Make sure it is a curl 7.21.7, because the previous one was broken for any ssh access.

As [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289247/error-from-intall-git-on-centos-6/7291350#7291350) (+1), you need **[curl-devel](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/curl-devel)**. There is only a libcurl-devel-7.19.7-16.el6.i686.rpm package which could be old enough for ssh to still work.

Comment: I already installed crul, but it still shows the error

Answer (score 0):

`libcurl.so.3` does come from curl package.

```
rpm -qf libcurl.so.3.0.0
curl-7.15.5-9.el5_6.2
```

I created a symbolic link on my system under `/usr/lib64`.

```
libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4.1.1
```

Comment: This looks like it was intended to be a comment to Keith Thompson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Git is included with the EL6 base repository; it's not necessary to install another repository to get access to it.

In the case of the original question, it looks like you are trying to use the rpmforge repo for EL5 on an EL6 system. Your best bet here is to fix or remove the repo from `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=8777

Changing el5 to el6 seems to do the job.

```
su root
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
for FILE in *; do mv $FILE $FILE.old; sed 's/el5/el6/g' $FILE.old > $FILE; done
yum clean all
```

This fixed it for me.